# Comparing two text files

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, csv

I have 2 big csv files, file1.csv which looks like this

```
1,2,3,4
1,4,5,6
1,7,8,9
1,11,13,17
```

file2.csv which looks like this

```
1,2,3,4
1,7,8,9
2,4,9,10
13,14,17,18
```

These are just random numbers that I made up, basically the two numbers where identical, and sorted. I want to compare file1.csv and file2.csv and then copy the rows that are present in file1.csv but not in file2.csv to file3.csv. the delimiter is comma obviously

I tried

```
comm -2 -3 file.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

and I tried

```
diff -u file.csv file2.csv >> file3.csv
```

Both didn't work because file3 was bigger than file1 and file2. I tried different `diff` and `comm` commands, sometimes it's bigger than file2 and about the same size as file file1, I know that file3 has to be significantly  less in size than file1 and  file2. And of course I looked at file3, not the results I wanted

At this point, I know it could be done with `diff` or `comm` but I do not know the command to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this command:

```
 grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv
```

According to [grep manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/grep.1.html):

```
  -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)

  -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

As Steeldriver said in his comment is better add also `-x` and `-F` that:

```
  -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
  -x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
          (-x is specified by POSIX.)
```

So, better command is:

```
 grep -xvFf file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv
```

This command use `file2.csv` line as pattern and print line of `file1.csv` that doesn't match (`-v`).

Comment: For *whole lines* that are *present in file1.csv but not in file2.csv* you probably want `grep -xvFf file2.csv file1.csv`

Comment: ops! I did a mistake reading question. thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 7):

In order to be able to use `comm`, you have to sort the lines first.

```
comm -23 <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > file3.csv
```

Comment: ... and the same holds for `diff`.

Answer (score 3):

A python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def readfile(file):
    with open(file) as src:
        return [line.strip() for line in src.readlines()]

lines_1 = readfile(sys.argv[1]); lines_2 = readfile(sys.argv[2])

for line in lines_1:
    if not line in lines_2:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
1,4,5,6
1,11,13,17
```

Paste the script into an empty file as `extract.py`, make it executable and run it by the command:

```
<script> <file_1> <file_2>
```

Or, to write it directly to file_3:

```
<script> <file_1> <file_2> >file_3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `diff` command do `grep` and no storing required.

Output if lines exist in file1 but not in file2:

```
$ diff file{1,2}.csv | grep -Po "^< \K.*"
1,4,5,6
1,11,13,17
```

And output if lines exist in file2 but not in file1, with just changing left angle(`<`) to right angle(`>`):

```
$ diff file{1,2}.csv | grep -Po "^> \K.*"
2,4,9,10
13,14,17,18
```